# How I can make this css style and jquery working with Clinic div like Doctor div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How I can make this css style and jquery working with Clinic div like Doctor div?
When I do the Clinic div like the Doctor div
The Clinic div stopped but the Doctor div work normally
so How I can make this css style and jquery working with Clinic div like Doctor div?

The html code:

```
<div id="wrap" class="sidebar" >
    <div id="sidebar" style="height: 150px;">
        <span id="toggleBtn">Doctor</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="cwrap" class="csidebar" >
    <div id="csidebar" style="height: 150px;">
        <span id="ctoggleBtn">Clinic</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS code:

```
#wrap {
    border: solid 1px #ccc; 
    width: 1355px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 20px; 
}
#sidebar {
    width: 220px; 
    position: fixed;
    top: 1em;
    right: 1em;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#wrap.sidebar #sidebar {
    right: -254px;
}

#wrap.sidebar #mainContent, #wrap.sidebar #sidebar {
    margin: 10px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #888;
}

.nosidebar #mainContent, #wrap #sidebar {
    margin: 10px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #888; 
}

#wrap.nosidebar #sidebar {
    right: 0; 
}

#sidebar #toggleBtn {
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px; 
    line-height: 30px; 
    background: #2191c0;
    color: white; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px;
    left: -60px; 
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

#sidebar #toggleBtn:hover {
    background: #6eac2c; 
}

#cwrap {
    border: solid 1px #ccc; 
    width: 1355px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 20px; 
}
#csidebar {
    width: 220px; 
    position: fixed;
    top: 1em;
    right: 1em;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#cwrap.csidebar #csidebar {
    right: -254px;
}

#cwrap.csidebar #cmainContent, #cwrap.csidebar #csidebar {
    margin: 10px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #888;
}

.cnosidebar #cmainContent, #cwrap #csidebar {
    margin: 10px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #888; 
}

#cwrap.cnosidebar #csidebar {
    right: 0; 
}

#csidebar #ctoggleBtn {
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px; 
    line-height: 30px; 
    background: #2191c0;
    color: white; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50px;
    left: -60px; 
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

#csidebar #ctoggleBtn:hover {
    background: #6eac2c; 
}
```

The JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Variables
    var objMain = $('#wrap');
    var objSidebar = $('#nosidebar');
    var objContent = $('#mainContent'); 

    // Show sidebar
    function showSidebar() {
        objMain.removeClass('nosidebar');
        objMain.addClass('sidebar');
        objSidebar.animate({ 'right' : '-254px'},'slow');
        objContent.animate({ 'margin-right': 270}, 'slow');
        $.cookie('sidebar-pref2', 'use-sidebar', { expires: 30 });
    }

    // Hide sidebar
    function hideSidebar() {
        objMain.removeClass('sidebar');
        objMain.addClass('nosidebar');
        objSidebar.animate({ 'right' : '0'},'slow');
        objContent.animate({ 'margin-right': 0}, 'slow');
        $.cookie('sidebar-pref2', null, { expires: 30 });
    }

    // Sidebar separator
    var objSeparator = $('#toggleBtn');

    objSeparator.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ( objMain.hasClass('nosidebar') ){
            showSidebar();
        }
        else {
            hideSidebar();
        }
    });

    // Load preference
    if ( $.cookie('sidebar-pref2') == null ){
        objMain.removeClass('sidebar');
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please better "define" your question? Or provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: when i use this style with the jquery method to slide the clinic div and doctor div it works only on doctor div
i want to make it works on the clinic div like the doctor div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this JSFiddle and tell if you want like this.....

http://jsfiddle.net/wWtnC/4/

Comment: And now, could you post your answer to the question in the *answers* to the question?